# How can I use zips with --py-files on pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to write some pyspark jobs that depend on a module that I want to include with the job, rather than installing on the clusters globally.

I decided to try doing this with zip files, but I can't seem to get it to work and I can't seem to find an example of doing this in the wild either.

I'm building the zip by running:

```
mkdir -p ./build
cd ./build && python ../src/setup.py sdist --formats=zip
```

This creates a file called `./build/dist/mysparklib-0.1.zip`. So far, so good.

My job looks like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

# See: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

readme_filename = './README.md'

sc = SparkContext('local', 'helloworld app')

readme_data = sc.textFile(readme_filename).cache()

def test_a_filter(s):
    import mysparklib
    return 'a' in s

a_s = readme_data.filter(test_a_filter).count()
b_s = readme_data.filter(lambda s: 'b' in s).count()

print("""
**************************************
* Lines with a: {}; Lines with b: {} *
**************************************
""".format(a_s, b_s))

sc.stop()
```

(this is mostly adopted from the quickstart, with the exception of me trying to import my module inside one of the filters.)

I'm kicking off the job by running:

```
spark-submit --master local[4] --py-files './build/dist/mysparklib-0.1.zip' ./jobs/helloworld.py
```

and while I see that the zip file *is* included:

```
17/05/17 17:15:31 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/./build/dist/mysparklib-0.1.zip at file:/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/./build/dist/mysparklib-0.1.zip with timestamp 1495055731604
```

it won't import:

```
17/05/17 17:15:34 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at /Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/./jobs/helloworld.py:15) failed in 1.162 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2408, in pipeline_func
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2408, in pipeline_func
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2408, in pipeline_func
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 345, in func
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1040, in <lambda>
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1040, in <genexpr>
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/mycompany/myproject/./jobs/helloworld.py", line 12, in test_a_filter
    import mysparklib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysparklib'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For a sanity check, I ran `python setup.py develop` inside mysparklib and tried importing it on the cli, and that works swimmingly.

Any ideas?

Comment: A dead end (?) I ran into:

I unzipped my package to see what was in it. It was missing mysparklib. Very strange! So I changed 2 things: 1) I started running the sdist command inside the ./src folder; and 2) I changed the packages parameter to be hard-coded to include mysparklib, rather than counting on find_packages() to do the right thing

Now when I unzip the tarball, it contains my package, but pyspark still fails!

Comment: (I've confirmed that I can pip install the zipball and have that do the right thing.)

Answer (score 2):

So I got this working! The core problem is that the directory structure of a sdist is not the structure that python is expecting when a zip is added to the module path (which is how `--py-files` works; you can confirm this by printing `sys.path`). In particular, the sdist zip has the file `./mysparklib-0.1/mysparklib/__init__.py`, but we need a zip with the file `./mysparklib/__init__.py` instead.

So instead of running

```
cd ./build && python ../src/setup.py sdist --formats=zip
```

I'm now running

```
cd ./src && zip ../dist/mysparklib.zip -r ./mysparklib
```

and that works.